# caliburn micro send data to the dialog

Tags: c#, caliburn.micro, coroutine

and sorry for the noobness, i'm fairly new to the framework, but i'm beginning to understand it and it's inner workings.

simply put what i want is this:
the shellview recieves an event, from something that happened on a view, logs the problem and shows a dialog informing the user that something wrong happened.

for the creation of the dialog i used [this](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/discussions/250303) thread and it works without any problems, but i'm lost on how to set the property Message on the view/ViewModel.

help would be appreciated

thanks in advance

Comment: can anyone provide me with a solution or at least showing me what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the [WindowManager](http://www.mindscapehq.com/blog/index.php/2012/03/13/caliburn-micro-part-5-the-window-manager) directly. Alternatively, you could adapt the code to create a `ShowDialog` constructor which takes an existing instance of your dialog view model.

In fact that code is a bit messy, `ShowDialog` should really be generic and take the type of the dialog view model, so that a cast isn't required in order to get the dialog result.

Comment: thanks for the help it works now. i followed what you've said and changed the code and now it works. it took some time and some trial and error but it's working.